# SQL Server Replication questions

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication

I'm Brazilian and I'm not very good English, I apologize.

I have a problem: before replication when replicating tables I wanted to set some rules for some columns not to be replicated, or be replicated with a default value.

```
id | descrisaoProduto | estoque 
1  | abcd             | 10
```

on replication

```
id | descrisaoProduto        | estoque
1  | (null or value default) | 10**
```

And find out if there is any way that when it is replicated, it convert a table to another.

```
id | estoqueLocal | estoqueMatriz
1  | 10           | 0
```

on replication

(replication)

```
id | estoqueLocal | estoqueMatriz
1  | 0            | 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to accomplish this would be to create a view representing the data you wish the subscriber to see, and then replicate that view instead of the underlying source table.  [Views can be replicated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx) as easily as tables.

In your scenario, you would want to replicate an indexed view as a table on the subscriber side.  In this way, you would not need to replicate the underlying table.  From the article above:

> For indexed views, transactional replication also allows you to replicate the indexed view as a table rather than a view, eliminating the need to also replicate the base table. To do this, specify one of the "indexed view logbased" options for the @type parameter of sp_addarticle (Transact-SQL).

[Here's an article](http://sqlship.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/replicate-indexed-views-transactional-replication/) demonstrating how to set up replication of an indexed view with transactional replication.